# Named pipes over network: Account restrictions

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I am currently creating a small client - server application where the server is located on one machine in the same network and the client is located at a second (different) machine on the same network.

Therefor I have created a servercode which looks like this:

```
PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Everyone", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance, AccessControlType.Allow));
var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesOfPiece", PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 0, 0, pipeSecurity);
server.WaitForConnection();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);
while (true) {
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    writer.WriteLine(String.Join("", line.Reverse()));
    writer.Flush();
}
```

And a client application which looks like this:

```
var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("DESKTOP-K7TUEGS", "PipesOfPiece");
client.Connect();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client);

while (true) {
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;
    writer.WriteLine(input);
    writer.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

When testing the two applications locally they work fine as expected, however if I try it on two different machines in the same network the client receives following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.
```

Do named pipes only work when both machines are in a domain? My current setup is a LAN without a Windows domain, only a router.
Or how can I setup the pipe server that everybody is able to connect?

EDIT: I also tried disabling the firewall, which did not change the situation.

Comment: You need to provide the name of the server NamedPipeClientStream should connect to. If you only provide the pipe name it will try to connect to the local computer. According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream you probably want NamedPipeClientStream("ServerName","PipesOfPiece")

Comment: Sorry for that, I also tried it. I used the hostname of my computer as the servername, but still receive the same error.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the documentation that the constructor for NamedPipeServerStream accepts a PipeSecurity parameter? Does your server build and run with the code in your post? From what I can tell you should use server.SetAccessControl(pipeSecurity)

Comment: yes it compiles and runs, there is an overload with following parameters: public NamedPipeServerStream(string pipeName, PipeDirection direction, int maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options, int inBufferSize, int outBufferSize, PipeSecurity pipeSecurity);

Comment: I also tried to use server.SetAccessControle(pipeSecurity) with the same error

Comment: What happens if you don't pass the pipeSecurity object to the constructor at all?

Comment: The same error. I created the server without the pipeSecurity (only with the pipename and direction in the constructor) and added it afterwards with your method / also tried to not add it at all. All with the same result

Comment: Is it possible that named pipes only work in an active directory (Windows domain)?

Comment: _"Is it possible that named pipes only work in an active directory"_ -- no, they work fine in any environment. It sounds like you might be trying to connect to the server using an account that has a blank password. That's not allowed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well I tried both, server with and without a password and the client with and without the password :/